# How to interpolate a value in ForEach() C#

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I have a foreach loop that I need to interpolate and add values to a list.
I have model that I need to select from.

here are the POCOs I use for the selection.

```
public class Data
    {
        
        public int UnixTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime UnixDateTime { get; set; }
        public float TestTime { get; set; }
        public float AirTemp { get; set; }
        public float RH { get; set; }
        public float SurfaceTemp { get; set; }
        public double LowFreq { get; set; }

    }
```

EDIT:

```
    var userType = "RH"; // Statically typed here, but it gets passed in as a parameter on a method not included. 
   

    foreach (var item in GetListOfSensorData)
    {
     Two separate lists I add to. 
      unixTimeList.Add(item.UnixTime);
       
      //I could hard code item.TestTime .. AirTemp .. etc
      // I didn't want to do that. I want to concatenate or 
      //  interpolate that string onto item 
       
      selectedDataList.Add(item. "interpolate here"); 
    }
```

A user makes this selection. I didn't want to make a bunch of if conditions so I thought interpolate would work.

What I have tried: Multiple ways to concatenate and interpolate the value. I don't get the values back when using interpolation.

What I'm hoping for:
When I hard code the value  selectedDataList.Add(item.RH); I get the values I'm looking
for. I don't get the results when I interpolate. I get a concatenated string basically.

Is there a way to interpolate the item I'm looking for in the foreach loop?

Screen shot of what I'm seeing from the interpolation.

[image]

Compared to when I hard code the value

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like `item.GetType().GetProperty(userType).GetValue(item).ToString()`? (There's a reason that's clunky, what with C# being a statically typed language and all.)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  what are the datatypes for `GetListOfSensorData` and `selectedDataList`.  Also can you give an example of an interpolated string?  what errors are you receiving?

Comment: @JeroenMostert That was exactly what I was looking for. I understand it's statically typed, I was merely trying to avoid statically typing each possible choice. All the user was doing was choosing between those 7 POCOs. I wanted concatenate their choice to the item. Thank you for the assist. I removed the ToString() and got exactly what I needed. item.GetType().GetProperty(Type).GetValue(item)

Comment: IF you are serializing and deserializing data and its loosely structured, you can try to use `Dictionary<string,string>` and JSON.  You can use the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()/DeserializeObject<T>()` -- this is especially helpful if you do not want to deal with a static model and / or .NET Reflection

Comment: @GlennFerrie That's fair. I can see the ambiguity. Jeroen hooked me up with what I was seeking, but I'll post a screen shot of what I was getting prior if you need.

Comment: Note that using `GetType().GetProperty()` is fairly expensive, and it wouldn't be a bad idea  to cache the result, or even better, a `Func<>` accessor method, in a `Dictionary` so you can do a faster lookup when using it. I use an extension method that caches automatically.